# Is it possible to install specific version of scala via rscala::scalaInstall()?

Tags: r, scala

Is it possible to install specific version of scala via `rscala::scalaInstall()` ?

Currently it installs 2.12.1 which my project doesn't support yet.

I'm also ok with installing 2.11.8 manually but then it's unclear to me how to point R to it. Shall I add `SCALA_HOME` env var to script that launches RStudio or is there better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to add scala to your path and you should be fine.

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rscala/README

Comment: What's the meaning of `add the "scala" script to the path` ? I unpacked `scala-2.11.11` to `~/.rscala` but R doesn't see it.

Comment: When you install scala it should create a file called "scala" somewhere.  Make sure you add that location to your path.  If you don't know what I'm talking about then google "adding directory to path" or something like that for details in whatever operating system you're using.